# How to associate full page curl animation for modalviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, page-curl

Currently I am showing a modal view controller for some info .

I want to show or hide the modal view controller with full page curl animation .

Currently I am showing this modal view controller from one of the view controller of the tab bar controller .

I have the option of partialpagecurl in the modalTransitionStyle property of the modalviewcontroller to be displayed .

Current code :

```
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;



    [self presentModalViewController:infoViewController animated:YES];

    [infoViewController release];
```

So How can I associate a full page curl transition or animation with a modalviewcontroller .

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: This snippet I am aware of but where to set it I am not aware of .

Comment: This snippet given by @ohho is very useful, but it would be great to know more on how to use this for transitions between view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the following code in **viewDidAppear** and **viewWillDisappear** calls in the view controller you want to present as modal

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:1.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                animations:^(void) {

                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (true == finished) {

                    }

                }];
```

You can keep an extra flag in viewcontroller class so that you can enable/disable the page curl as required.